# Why is it sometimes valid to write an include statement in a codeblock?

Tags: c, include

I amcoming from a python background, where the following is valid:

```
def f():
    import someLibrary
    someLibrary.libraryFunction()
```

So when I needed to debug C code, I wrote, in the middle of my function:

```
void f(int param)
{
     int status;
     /* other code */
     #include <stdio.h>
     printf("status: %d", status);
     /* more code */
}
```

And it compiled and worked as I expected. Later it was pointed out to me that this shouldn't compile, since the C pre-processor literally replaces the `#include~ statement with the contents of`stdio.h`.
So why was this valid code?

Comment: Header files usually contain declarations. So the code can compile but does not make great sense.:) Moreover due to header guards the compiler will not include a header if it is already included above.

Comment: When you `#include` something, it is simply the same as you would copy and paste that file content into this location. So that content might or might not make the final result compilable.

Comment: `#include someLibrary` in Python won't do anything useful, as it's a comment. Do you perhaps mean `import someLibrary`? That does something *completely different* than the preprocessor `#include` directive.

Comment: FYI, although it might not get a compiler error, as stated in [Nikos C.’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56346906/298225), it violates C 2018 7.1.2 4: “… If used, a [standard library] header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition,….”

Answer (score 0):

> it was pointed out to me that this shouldn't compile, since the C pre-processor literally replaces the #include statement with the contents ofstdio.h.

The logic on that doesn't make sense. Just because the pre-processor inserts the text from the `stdio.h` file doesn't mean it should not compile. If there's nothing in that file that would result in a compile error, then it will compile just fine.

Furthermore, headers usually have a multiple inclusion guard in them. So if they were included already previously, any further attempts to include it have no effect. In this case, if `<stdio.h>` was already included previously in the file (directly or indirectly), the `#include` will have no effect.

With that being said, don't do that though. In C, standard headers are not supposed to be included while inside a function scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, C and Python are pretty different in this respect.

It is correct that the preprocessor replaces the `#include` directive with the contents of the included file prior to compilation.

Whether it leads to a compilation error or not depends entirely on the contents of the included file.  Standard headers like `stdio.h` don't contain any executable statements - they only contain things like typdefs, function declarations, other macros, etc.  They also usually have some kind of `#include` guards in place that prevent them from being loaded more than once per translation unit (that is, if you `#include` a file that includes `stdio.h`, and then `#include <stdio.h>` directly in the same source file, the contents of `stdio.h` will only be loaded once).

*Theoretically*, there's no problem with including `stdio.h` at random points in the code, but it can lead to problems.  In this case all of `stdio.h`'s contents will only be visible to the body of `f` - not a problem if only `f` needs to use anything in `stdio.h`, but otherwise it will lead to headaches.

Standard headers are best included at the beginning of the source file.